# exclude content field from crispy forms

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-templates, django-crispy-forms

forms.py

```
from django import forms
from tinymce import TinyMCE
from .models import Article


class TinyMCEWidget(TinyMCE):
    def use_required_attribute(self, *args):
        return False


class PostForm(forms.ModelForm):
    content = forms.CharField(
        widget=TinyMCEWidget(
            attrs={'required': False, 'cols': 30, 'rows': 10}
        )
    )

    class Meta:
        model = Article
        fields = ('title', 'major', 'semester', 'book', 'unit', 'content')
```

article_form.html

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% load static %}
{% load tailwind_filters %}
{% block title %}Create{% endblock title %}

{% block content %}

    {{ form.media }}
    <div class="row form-error">
        <div class="column" id="content">
            <form  method="post" action='' enctype="multipart/form-data">
                {% csrf_token %}
                {{ form|crispy }}
                <input class="button" type="submit" value="Save">
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>

{% endblock %}
```

I using TinyMCE to implement a rich text editor.
when I reload the page it gives me this:

```
AttributeError at /article/new/
'CSSContainer' object has no attribute 'tinymce'
```

I just want to use crispy forms on all fields and exclude the content field from crispy forms.

Comment: have you added **STATIC_ROOT** for tinymce

Comment: no!! I know should be added but I haven't (yet).

Comment: tinymce needs **STATIC_ROOT** so add and then try

Comment: tried it but the same error.

Comment: I found a solution check the answer, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I did some google and I found this

[[simpleisbetterthancomplex.com](https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2018/11/28/advanced-form-rendering-with-django-crispy-forms.html)]

then I modified my code to:

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% load static %}
{% load tailwind_filters %}
{% block title %}Create{% endblock title %}

{% block content %}

    {{ form.media }}
    <div class="row form-error">
        <div class="column" id="content">
            <form  method="post" action='' enctype="multipart/form-data">
                {% csrf_token %}
                {{ form.title|as_crispy_field  }}
                {{ form.major|as_crispy_field  }}
                {{ form.semester|as_crispy_field  }}
                {{ form.book|as_crispy_field  }}
                {{ form.unit|as_crispy_field  }}
                {{ form.content }}
                <input class="button" type="submit" value="Save">
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>

{% endblock %}
```